# How to call the base method in an inherited class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, babeljs, create-react-app

Well I wish to do something seemingly simple: call the base method from an inherited function. I'm doing this in a `create-react-scripts` environment for babel, the script would look like (which is about as minimal as it can get):

```
import * as React from react;

class base {
    constructor() {
        this.data = 'blah';
    }
    foo = () => {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}

class child extends base{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.childData = 'ok';
    }
    foo = () => {
        super.foo();
        console.log(this.childData);
    }
}

const Main = class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const c = new child();
        c.foo();
    }
    render() {
        return <div>test</div>
    }
}
```

Now this immediately complains (only first error seems to contain information):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

The above error occurred in the <Main> component:
    in Main (at App.js:62)
    in div (at App.js:62)
    in Route (at App.js:62)
    in Router (at App.js:61)
    in MuiPickersUtilsProvider (at App.js:60)
    in Provider (at App.js:59)
    in ThemeProvider (at App.js:58)
    in div (at App.js:58)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

checking shows this happens due to the line `super.foo()` in the `child.foo` function.

What is happening here? And how do I call the base's foo from the child foo?

---

Relevant information:

```
list -g create-react-app
└── create-react-app@2.0.3 

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.99.0",
  },
```

Comment: I think the issue is your use of `arrow notation` ... change each `foo = () => {` to `foo() {` and it will work

Comment: @JaromandaX - and it will break at other spots due to not binding `this`. (If I bind the function manually in the constructor, or even at location where the function will be passed as reference the same problem occurs).

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me, sorry

Comment: @JaromandaX The function is passed around as reference. As such `this` is bound to "something else" when the function is called; this is unwanted and breaks stuff. To  prevent this I used arrow functions. (Or I could manually bind `this`) - however doing so will lead to my original problem.

Comment: @paul23 If you use method definition syntax in both `base` and `child`, and do `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)` in the constructor, it *will* work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the arrow function is the problem.

Details on the problem are here:

[Arrow Functions in Class Properties Might Not Be As Great As We Think](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

> Arrow functions in class properties won’t be in the prototype and we can’t call them with super.

---

- I think arrow function is a great thing, I would rename one of them and forget overriding forever :)
- Since you are using Babel this could be useful too: [autobind-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator)

Also binding every method considered a bad practice. It can cause performance issues at large scale. Bind only the ones needed seems better.

Comment: Renaming and "forgetting" overriding means forgetting one of the most powerful tools in programming: polymorphism.

Comment: I edited my answer. Put a smile at the end of that line so it's more clear it is a joke. I think the best solution is autobind-decorator, but now that you know the root cause of the problem there is a lot of solution can solve it based on your needs.